# IIS Express only runs .NET 3.5 websites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I cannot run/debug ASP.NET .NET >= 4.0 applications through IIS Express: Access denied.
When I switch to .NET 3.5 everything runs fine. Could this be because the .NET 3.5 installation was executed after .NET 4.xx?
Checked both the applicationhost.configs under .vs\configuration and in %user%\documents folder; no strange setup here (= default settings).
I've reïnstalled iisexpress => no success.
Created a new local admin user => no success.

No usefull information is logged under documents\iisexpress\tracelogfiles.
When debugging and breaking all Gac assemblies are loaded but the project dll is not. 
I've always tested with a new, clean asp.net empty web application.

Note: I do have 'Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)' installed. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Did you configure the site to use .NET 4 Runtime?  How exactly are you using IIS Express?  This should be done automatically if you're configuring it through Visual Studio.

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach a screen shot ? Do you get access denied on a page, or as a Windows prompt. Could you try running VS in the administrator role

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where after upgrading a legacy app to .Net Framework 4.x IIS Express was running under .Net Framework 3.5, which caused similar issues. Actually looking for an alternate solution for the below, however here is the fix I've used for IIS express not running dot net framework 4:

In your web.config find `system.web` section and for property `httpRuntime` set the `targetFarmework`  to `4.x.x` (replace x with your specific .Net Framework version).